# On some devices with 2.3 my game written in Angnegine GLES2 not working

Tags: android, andengine

On some devices like Galaxy Young my game written in andengine GLES 2.0 is crashing when activity is started.
The minSdkVersion is set to 10, so it cannot be the version problem.
Also need to mention that camera size is set by me to 1280x800, and all textureAtlasses are 1024x1024 size.

Also, I make a very simple test program  in the same version, and run on that device, and its worket with no problem.

Comment: Without *some* indication of what the crash is, it's going to be hard to troubleshoot. Can you get your hands on a stack trace or crash report?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have stack for that crashes...I do not have device that I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as the name suggests  andengine GLES 2.0 uses Open GL ES 2, does that phone support that (It may only support Open GL ES 1) ? I would suggest adding the correct fields in the manifest that stop the app from being installed on devices without this requirement.

Here is the XML you will need to add

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

And if your phone doesn't have Open GL ES 2 then android won't let you install / run it.

Here is some more information on Open GL ES for android.

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

Comment: How to make this exception in manifest? I tried to put <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/> but with no effect?

Comment: Does that line filters devices only on google play?

Comment: It would filter them on Google Play, sorry I got confused. But you can check if your device supports Open GLES 2 here http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_young_s6310-5280.php

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to insert it on the next update.